# While showing a toast in android code, I get the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: setView must have been called

Tags: android-toast

Code I am using:

```
Toast t = new Toast(this);
t.makeText(this, "You clicked the button..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
t.show();
```

[ I know I can use:

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked the button..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
t.show()
```

but I want to know the problem with the code snippet at the top ]

Detailed Error Log:

```
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    ... 11 more
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setView must have been called
12-07 15:09:58.333: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.Toast.show(Toast.java:114)
```

Comment: The issue is that in your first implementation you are creating two toasts and attempting to show the which has not yet had its view set. This will cause an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the one you are using is not the suggested method. Obviously the constructor is public but it is not supposed to be used in this way.

Your code segment calling static method makeText actually makes no change to the Toast object t

But in the Toast t=Toast.makeText(...); example, the Toast t is the return value of Toast.makeText

Comment: Ok, got it !! So, I should write like this: 
`Toast t = new Toast(this); t = Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked the button..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); t.show();`

if I necessarily want to use the constructor to take the return value of makeText() method in object 't'. 

Thanks!